# How to perform logging in C# Incremental Source Generator?

Tags: .net-core, roslyn

I'm building a new C# Source Generator and I couldn't find any proper documentation on how to do logging/outputting of diagnostics information. Is it possible? Otherwise, what's the current recommended way of debugging a execution?